# Is there a way to Collapse All json's fields in Postman

Tags: json, postman, json-view

I'm working with the chrome-app Postman, and im retriving sometimes long and complex json objects.
For an easy work i need to collapse all the json object, but i can't find the option (if there is) in the program, or how to do it.
Until now, i'm using another app (JsonViewer) just for a better view of the result.

Is there a way to collapse all the json fields in the app?

for example
from:

```
{
  "some object" : {
      "some att" : "foo",
      "other att" : "bar"
    },
  "somearray" : [
     "asdf",
     "qwer",
     "zxcv"
  ]
}
```

to:

```
{
  "some object" : { + },
  "somearray" : [ + ]
}
```

PD: I know there is an option to collapse field by field the json but what i want is to collapse all the object. 
In large objects that feature is highly appreciated

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You should be able to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> to collapse all and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> to uncollapse.

Was an issue [here](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1257) which points to all shortcuts working from [ace](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Default-Keyboard-Shortcuts).

Answer (score 49):

On Mac it's <kbd>Command⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Option⌥</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> to collapse all and <kbd>Command⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Option⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Shift⇧</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> to uncollapse.

Comment: how to collapse a specific level of the response tree ?

Comment: This will collapse all the response

Comment: Oh, now I see, once you collapse all, you can start to uncollapse the objects you want, kind of time-consuming in a complex JSON but better than nothing.